# ConfigMap for PODS created for Batch jobs launched from SCDF

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow, configmap

I launch Spring batch jobs from SCDF. Batch application is deployed as docker image in openshift environment. And SCDF is running in the same openshift environment under same namespace as of docker image.

The config-map created for SCDF is working well. But when I add the Batch Project's application.yaml to openshift config-map, it's not being referred by the POD when it is being launched from SCDF. I have given the same name for "spring.applciation.name" and config-map's "metadata.name". Also I added the below properties in batch application. But it's of no use. The properties from config-map are not read.

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: batch-app
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        name: batch-app
        namespace: batch-app-qa
        sources:
        - name: batch-app
```

**config-map.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metaData:
  name: batch-app
  namespace: batch-app-qa
  labels:
    app: batch-app
data:
  application.properties: |-
    message=In QA Environment
    spring.datasource.batch.password=**********
    spring.datasource.batch2.password=********
```

**Job/POD Logs:**

```
[main] WARN  org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySource.getData - Can't read configMap with name: [batch-app] in namespace:[batch-app-qa]. Ignoring.
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [ConfigMap]  with name: [batch-app]  in namespace: [batch-app-qa]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72) ~[kubernetes-client-4.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:229) ~[kubernetes-client-4.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:162) ~[kubernetes-client-4.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySource.getData(ConfigMapPropertySource.java:95) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-config-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySource.<init>(ConfigMapPropertySource.java:76) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-config-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.getMapPropertySourceForSingleConfigMap(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:95) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-config-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.lambda$locate$0(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:78) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-config-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.2.RELEASE]

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(java.base@9-internal/Alerts.java:214) ~[na:na]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(java.base@9-internal/SSLSocketImpl.java:1962) ~[na:na]

[main] INFO  org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize - Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configmap.batch-app.batch-app-qa'}]
```

**SCDF LOGS when Running a Job**

```
2020-07-24 12:24:33.479  WARN 1 --- [-nio-80-exec-10] ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver : Failed to retrieve properties for resource:Docker Resource [docker:docker-registry.default.svc:5000/batch-app-qa/batch-job]   ---> **This is the Batch Application being loaded into scdf for job launch**

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.container.DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.getRegistryRequest(DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.java:162) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-configuration-metadata-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.container.DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.getImageLabels(DefaultContainerImageMetadataResolver.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-configuration-metadata-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.resolvePropertiesFromContainerImage(BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.java:157) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-configuration-metadata-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.listProperties(BootApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolver.java:134) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-configuration-metadata-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.WhitelistProperties.qualifyProperties(WhitelistProperties.java:62) [spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.TaskServiceUtils.mergeAndExpandAppProperties(TaskServiceUtils.java:164) [spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.TaskAppDeploymentRequestCreator.createRequest(TaskAppDeploymentRequestCreator.java:115) [spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService.executeTask(DefaultTaskExecutionService.java:258) [spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$422cda43.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskExecutionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d03bb9f.executeTask(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.TaskExecutionController.launch(TaskExecutionController.java:172) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
```

How to provide the config map for the pod being launched from SCDF. Since the Spring boot batch application doesn't have/need a deployment config file, how do I specify the boot batch application to refer the config-map when it's launched as pod from scdf?

Thanks.

Comment: is your `docker-registry.default.svc:5000` (where the batch-app-qa/batch-job is resolved from) docker registry protected with secrets? are they mounted?

Some general information about how to configure the private docker registry is available here: https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.6.0.SNAPSHOT/feature-guides/general/application-metadata/#using-metadata-container-image-labels

Comment: Docker registry is at same place where SCDF running. I can pull the image run the Job inside of it. But jobs doesn't find or locate the config-map when they are launched from SCDF.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass some configs for your task apps, you can either have your configs in your spring cloud config and pass the cloud config url as environmental variables for the task app or pass the configuration directly as environmental variables as well.

[how to pass environment variables are documented in this SCDF documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_environment_variables)